# How many non-homeomorphic topological structures are there on a finite set of order $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology

Given a finite set of order $n$, how many different (that is, non-homeomorphic) topological structures are there on this set?

It is a question about topology but my feeling is that it is essentially a question in combinatorics.

Comment: This is a very hard problem.  Some efforts are here:  http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/REUNotes2010/FiniteSpaces.pdf

Comment: For low values of n: https://oeis.org/A000798

Comment: See the references in the [OEIS sequence A001930](https://oeis.org/A001930) which is the number of non-homeomorphic (or unlabeled) topologies. A000798 is the total number of different topologies.

Comment: This may be a duplicate. Also see the discussion and links available at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582662/classification-of-finite-topologies/1583230

Comment: You will find information about the combinatorial-language version of the problem at that question - e.g. finite spaces are equivalent to a certain class of posets.

Answer (score 0):

A topology $\tau$ on the set $X$ is (generated by) a set of subsets of $X$.  So $\tau\in P(P(X))$.

Let $\mid X\mid=n$.  Then $\mid P(P(X))\mid =2^{{2^n}}$.  This gives (at least) an upper bound on the number.

Since the subset must contain the $\emptyset$ and the whole set X, the inequality is strict.

Because of this, we should be able to (marginally, to use @Arturo Magidin's description ) improve it to $2^{2^n-2}=\frac{2^{2^n}}4$.

Comment: This is rather naive... you can improve it marginally without too much work by noting that whatever $\tau$ is, it must include both $\varnothing$ and the whole set.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin not to mention the action of the group of self-bijections of $n$, since we're counting homeomorphism classes. Well, on second thought, I guess the orbits of this action are probably too complicated to easily lower the bound.

Comment: @KevinCarlson That strikes me as a little harder (and not nearly as mindless as mine), since the orbits are not all the same size...