# List all topologies of $X = \{1,2,3\}$ up to homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, problem-solving

Problem 2-2 in Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* reads:

> Let $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Give a list of topologies on $X$ such that
> every topology on $X$ is  homeomorphic to exactly one on your list.

Below is my attempted solution. Is there a more efficient way to solve a problem like this one? My method felt a bit tedious.

---

The topologies can be partitioned into classes according to how many 1- and 2-element sets they contain. Let us write $(m, n) \in \{0, \dotsc, 3\}^2$ to represent each such class, with $m$ being the number of 1-element sets (singletons) and $n$ the number of 2-element sets in the topology, and go through each of them. Note that homeomorphisms preserve class membership.

- (0,0) This class contains only the trivial topology $\{X, \varnothing\}$.
- (1,0) If we add a single singleton to the trivial topology we obtain a topology homeomorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}\}$.
- (2,0) This class is empty, since if we have two singletons we must also have the 2-element set given by their union.
- (3,0) Similarly empty.
- (0,1) Adding a 2-element set to the trivial topology we obtain a topology homeomorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1, 2\}\}$.
- (1,1) There are two distinct ways we can add a singleton and a 2-element set to the trivial topology; either they overlap or they do not. Hence we either get a topology homeomorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}\}$, or one homeomorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{2, 3\}\}$. Note that these are not homeomorphic to each other. (A homeomorphism would have to map $\{1\}$ to $\{1\}$, but simultaneously map $\{1,2\}$ to $\{2,3\}$, which is impossible.)
- (2,1) All topologies in this class are hoemorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}$, since a topology with two singletons must also contain their union.
- (3,1) All three singletons together generate the discrete topology, so this class is empty.
- (0,2) If we have two 2-element sets they must overlap on a single element, thus giving us also a singleton via closure under finite intersection. Hence this class is empty.
- (1,2) By the logic above, the topologies in this class are all homeomorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}$.
- (2,2) These topologies must have a (1,2)-topology as a subset, by the logic
  above. Hence they are homeomorphic to $\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\}$.
- (3,2) Again, only the discrete topology contains all three singletons.
- (0,3) With all three 2-element sets we get all the singletons via intersections, hence this class is empty.
- (1,3) Similarly empty.
- (2,3) Similarly empty.
- (3,3) Here we have only the discrete topology, $\mathcal P(X)$.

Hence every topology on $X$ is homeomorphic to exactly one of the following topologies:
$$\{X, \varnothing\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1, 2\}\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{2, 3\}\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\},$$
$$\{X, \varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}\},$$
$$\mathcal P(X).$$

Comment: Its good to include a subject in your tags, general-topology in this case. Also solution-verification questions of the form "is my proof correct" are off-topic (see tag description for more details). I've deleted the question about your proof being correct, since the tag problem-solving still applies (i.e. what's the right method to solve the question), I see no further problems though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the repeated string of symbols $\varnothing\, \{1\}$ should be $\varnothing, \{1\}$. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

For a discussion of the difficulties of this problem in the general case see [this math.stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090347/how-many-non-homeomorphic-topological-structures-are-there-on-a-finite-set-of-or). In the comments of that post you'll see a link there for the OEIS sequence that gives number of different topologies on an $n$-element set up to homeomorphism; for the case $n=3$ that list agrees with your count of 9 topologies.

Comment: Oh, yes of course. Fixed that typo now.

Comment: Is there a less "brute force" method?

Comment: Seems unlikely. This is a hard, combinatorial problem. Not deep, particularly... but hard in the computational sense.

Comment: I added a bit on the "difficulty" issue, with a link to a related post.